# size of item for using for loop in jsp from multiple ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, arraylist

I have created a page (let say query.jsp) asking for filter, and then the user keyed in the appropriate value and then submit the value to java class. The class then process the filter condition, and then pass the result in form of multiple ArrayList to query.jsp again. I'd managed to pass the data in form of object and casting them back to ArrayList in the query.jsp, but i don't really know how to make them iterate into each index.

sample of product data after casting

```
[GE1, T1, S1, GE1, GE4, GL1, T1, GE3, R1, GL5, E2, S6, GL5, GE1, GL1, GL5, S4, E5, S3, S6, GL6, T1, GL5, GL1, GE2, T1, R2, E1, E1, GL1, S2, S2, S6, GL3, S3, GE3, E1, S4, S3, GL2, R2, S6, S2, GL1, T4, GE2, S5, R1, GE1, S3, GL2, GE4, GL3, GE3, GL3, T3, GE5, E3, E2, T1, E2, E2, R2, GE5, GE1, GE1, GL1, GL1, GE3, T1]
```

Each data after casting means the position for certain people. let say the index of product[0] is for "a", same goes with company,company[0] is the data for "a", CName, validity and so on.

query.jsp

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Date from" id="datefrom" class="form-control" name="datefrom" required>
<input type="date" placeholder="Date to" id="dateto" class="form-control" name="dateto" required>
<select class="form-control" name="status" required>
<option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<option value="New">New</option>
<option value="Renew">Renew</option>    
</select>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">Creator</th>
        <th>Cost (USD)</th>
        <th class="hidden-xs"> Software license</th>
        <th>Current layout engine</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- START DUMPING DATA -->
    <% 
        ArrayList<String> product = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("product"); 
        ArrayList<String> company = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("company");
        ArrayList<String> CName = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("CName");
        ArrayList<String> validity = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("validity");
        ArrayList<String> unit = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("unit");
        ArrayList<String> totPrice = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("totPrice");

        for(int i=0, i<product.size(),i++)//what size should i put index?
        {%>
            <tr>product</tr>
            <tr>company</tr>
            <tr>CName</tr>
            <tr>validity</tr>
            <tr>unit</tr>
            <tr>totPrice</tr>
        %>
```

Comment: can Map support until 6 String? curious

Comment: nahh forget it haha i got the answer so thank you who come across this post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to redesign your code because all 6 lists are un-related and will have different sizes and that is causing the loop iterating issue. A better way is to create a POJO and then create a single list that will contain multiple instances of that POJO like the following:

Product.java

```
package com.test;

public class Product {
    private String product;
    private String company;
    private String CName;
    private String validity;
    private String unit;
    private String totPrice;

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getCName() {
        return CName;
    }

    public void setCName(String cName) {
        CName = cName;
    }

    public String getValidity() {
        return validity;
    }

    public void setValidity(String validity) {
        this.validity = validity;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public String getTotPrice() {
        return totPrice;
    }

    public void setTotPrice(String totPrice) {
        this.totPrice = totPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [product=" + product + ", company=" + company + ", CName=" + CName + ", validity=" + validity
                + ", unit=" + unit + ", totPrice=" + totPrice + "]";
    }

}
```

query.jsp

```
<!-- START DUMPING DATA -->
<% 
    ArrayList<Product> products = (ArrayList<Product>) request.getAttribute("products"); 

    for(Product product : products)
    {%>
      <tr>
        <td>product.getProduct()</td>
        <td>product.getCompany()</td>
        <td>product.getCName()</td>
        <td>product.getValidity()</td>
        <td>product.getUnit()</td>
        <td>product.getTotPrice()</td>
      </tr>
    %>
```

Comment: I also think it'd be wise to create this class but then logically each array contain the same amount index. so could it be wrong if i just get the product.size()? i mean is it performance wise?